# How to write a reusable DB transaction wrapper?

Tags: go, generics, transactions, reusability

I need to write a reusable function where part of it can be run before and after its invoked.

For example:

```
isNewTnx, rollback, beginErr := DbConnectionManager.Begin(req)

if beginErr != nil {
    return nil, beginErr
}

if isNewTnx {
    defer rollback()
}
```

Above code starts a transaction and if its a new transaction it controls it, meaning it can either `commit` or `rollback`. I'm forced to write this code in a lot of services. Any  way to make this more reusable? I know function currying is an option, any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses types from `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` as example. Given a data structure that wraps your database driver (mainly for interface implementation):

```
type Datastore struct {
    *sqlx.DB
}
```

You declare a method on it:

```
func (ds *Datastore) InTransaction(ctx context.Context, fn func(*sqlx.Tx) error) error {
    tx, err := ds.BeginTxx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("open tx error: %w", err)
    }
    defer tx.Rollback()

    if err := fn(tx); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("commit tx error: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here the trick is to always rollback with `defer tx.Rollback()`. If the transaction was successfully completed, rolling back does nothing. If an error occurred, it rolls back the transaction.

And then you use is as:

```
// ds := &Datastore{sqlx.MustConnect(.....)}

err := ds.InTransaction(ctx, func(tx *sqlx.Tx) error {
    // actual application code where you run SQL statements using `tx`
})
```

---

For functions that need to return something along with a possible error, you can use a generic wrapper around `InTransaction` function. Unfortunately this must be a top-level function that takes the datastore struct (or whatever appropriate interface) because methods can't have type parameters that weren't already defined on the receiver type:

```
// InTransaction is an adapter function to call InTransaction with an arbitrarily typed return pair.
func InTransaction[T any](ds *Datastore, ctx context.Context, fn func(tx *sqlx.Tx) (T, error)) (T, error) {
    // this is the possibly empty typed value we want to return
    var t T
    // this err is either the error produced by fn 
    // or the error produced by InTransaction itself, such as begin error, commit error, ...
    err := e.InTransaction(ctx, func(tx *sqlx.Tx) error {
        result, err := fn(tx)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // propagate the typed value from fn out of InTransaction
        t = result
        return nil
    })
    // return t — possibly empty depending on what fn returned or whether it was called at all — and err
    return t, err
}
```

And then you use it as:

```
// ds := &Datastore{sqlx.MustConnect(.....)}

myType, err := InTransaction(ds, ctx, func(tx *sqlx.Tx) (*MyType, error) {
    // actual application code where you run SQL statements using `tx`
    // and may return an arbitrary type and error
})
```